# How to save dataframe as separated csv files?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of dicts like this:

```py
sample = [
    {'title': title, 'description': description, 'category': category, 'URLS': [1, 3, 4]},
    {'title': title, 'description': description, 'category': category, 'URLS': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]},
    {'title': title, 'description': description, 'category': category, 'URLS': [1]}
]
```

This is loaded into the dataframe without any problems:

```py
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

There are a lot of such dictionaries, about 200,000 and a lot of categories, I want to save files sorted by categories into different csv files.

At first, I just tried to display all the elements for each category:

```py
for item in range(len(dataframe['category'])):
    dataframe['category'][item]
```

But i have output like this:

```
'Games & Hobbies'
'Video Games'
'Business'
...
```

Just to save all this is not a problem, but there are a lot of records and I would like to separate them.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby`

```
for x , y in df.groupby('category'):
    y.to_csv(x+'.csv')
```

Comment: why not use f strings (: nice answer as always

Comment: @Datanovice ah, just string adding is 1st come into my mind :-)

Answer (score 2):

something like :

```
for cat in df['category'].unique():
  df1 = df.loc[df['category'] == cat]
  df1.to_csv(f'{cat}.csv')
```

this will loop through your dataframe and save a csv per each unique category.